# Why data variables in Python are unchangable?

Tags: python

I have used C++ for several years and now I am going to study Python to make programs running on servers. Just now I read from a website that int and float variables in Python are unchangable, an assignment operation means a new object is produced. I feel confused about why Python designed like that. And, will it bring some problems in running efficiency?
English is not my native tongue, I am still learning English so that there maybe something incorrect. I really feel guilty about that.

example codes...

x = 1
id(x)
x = 2
id(x)
x += 2
id(x)

Comment: What do you mean by "data variables" actually ? attributes ? or dictionnary values ? If it's one of them, they're both changable

Comment: we are ready help you. can you please explain your problem along with your code ?

Comment: Please give the link to the website or further explanation on what you have read

Comment: like integer or float variables... @Nenri

Comment: what do you mean by "unchangable" then ? Cause they definitively are changable @666Volts

Comment: An assignment does **not** create a new object. It create a (new) reference also call a 'name' to the right side object. If this object is new or not depends on the right side expression.

Comment: Don't get confused by the ids they are subject of optimization in the CPython interpreter.

Comment: I think a changable variable means that codes like "var = 5" can modify the content stored in var directly... @Nenri

Comment: @666Volts just do `var = anythingElse`

Comment: It's written by Chinese... http://www.runoob.com/python3/python3-number.html @FlyingTeller

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have written some codes to show my thoughts just now. : D @Abhijith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, you need help on how variables are stored in memory and literally need to understand why Python creates a new object every time the value is assigned.

The below link has a very good explanation to your question with examples.

https://medium.com/broken-window/many-names-one-memory-address-122f78734cb6

Comment: That is exactly what I want. I have got it. Thanks. :D